# How to handle validation in WPF when binding to DbSet<T>.Local?

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, idataerrorinfo, inotifydataerrorinfo

`DbSet<T>.Local` provides an `ObservableCollection` that you can bind to WPF controls. In my case, I'm binding it to a grid.

If I was using view models, I would have them implement `INotifyDataErrorInfo` or `IDataErrorInfo`, and then write Fluent Validation validators to handle validation.

But here I'm binding to the models via `DbSet<T>.Local`. How should I handle validation?

Should I implement `INotifyDataErrorInfo` or `IDataErrorInfo` on my models?

Or is there some alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are application is a thick client, meaning all layers of the application are on a single physical machine, then you should implement `IDataErrorInfo` on your models.

On the other hand, if your application is a thin multi-tired application, meaning that your model is implemented on a server and you are using the WPF desktop application to communicate with the server side code then you should implement `INotifyDataErrorInfo`.

Comment: It's a think-client. Are there any alternatives that don't involve implementing either interface on the models themselves?

Comment: @cocowalla Well because you're accessing those objects from the Local cache i believe there is no other alternative, and this way validation logic would be tied to the model classes which is considered a good practice by many developers and they are interfaces so you can still derive from other base classes if you want to.

Answer (score 1):

Yes I think implement implementing IValidatableObject in POCO Models makes sense.
And you have probably noticed    `public ObservableCollection<TEntity> Local { get; }`

There are several ways to do this. So a some homework.

[As some background , might be useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191143/entity-framework-validation)

[Then check this out](http://www.headspring.com/entity-framework-code-first-dbcontext-validation/)

So we know  EF has the concept of triggering Validations.

```
Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = true;
```

EF will also call `IEnumerable<ValidationResult> ValidateInstance();`

from interface `IValidatableObject`

if your entity POCO implements `IValidatableObject`

EF will trigger validate on SAve.
You can also easily trigger validations when you need to.

This all neatly links in with UoW concept.

```
 public IEnumerable<DbEntityValidationResult> GetDbValidationErrors() { return 
        Context.GetValidationErrors(); }   // Standard Context call get the problems
```

which can be used
     catch (Exception ex) {....
        var x =  GetDbValidationErrors();
      //....

So i think you are on the right track...

**EDIT:  Add SAMPLE  POCOBase and demonstrate trigger validation.**

```
public interface IFBaseObject : IValidatableObject {
    // a POCO object must implement the VALIDATE method from    IValidatableObject
    bool IsValidInstance();
    IEnumerable<ValidationResult> ValidateInstance();

}

public abstract class BaseObject : IFBaseObject {

     // .... base object stuff removed....

    /// <summary>
    /// Get called every a Validation is trigger on an object.  Here we return and Empty resultset to start with.
    /// If you override ALWAYS call Base first and Continue to add your own results as desired.
    /// Never fail to call base First !
    /// </summary>
    public virtual IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext) {
        # region Sample implementation for a POCO thats needs validation

        /* Sample Implementation a sub type POCO might use.
         var validationResult = base.Validate(validationContext).ToList();  

         if (true) // the condition that leads to a validation error
         {
             var memberList = new List<string> { "PropertyName" }; // the name of the offending property
             var error = new ValidationResult("Error text goes here", memberList); // use teh textpool !!! no hardcoded texts
             validationResult.Add(error);
         }

         return validationResult;
       */

        # endregion

        // now back in the base Class.
        var validationResult = new List<ValidationResult>();
        // hand back a list that is empty so errors if any can be added by SUBclasses
        // we can check any Poco that implements a certain interface centrally.  
        var thisIsKeyGuid = this as IFKeyGuid;
        if (thisIsKeyGuid != null) {
            if (thisIsKeyGuid.Id == Guid.Empty) {
                validationResult.Add(new ValidationResult("Id is required", new List<string>() {"Id"}));
            }
        }

        return validationResult;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows explicit triggering of Validation and returns a TRUE or false answer. Call anytime
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public virtual bool IsValidInstance() {
        List<ValidationResult> vResults;
        return SelfValidation(out vResults);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Calls Self Validation which uses THIS object as the context for validation.
    /// This means you can trigger a validation without first declaring a validation context.
    /// IValidatableObject is effectively called for you. Witch causes "Validate" to be called
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> ValidateInstance() {
        List<ValidationResult> vResults;
        SelfValidation(out vResults);
        return vResults;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Although SelfValidation is defined at BaseObject level, this triggers the VALIDATION process on the current Object
    /// see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validator.aspx for mroe details
    /// So if a POCO Object has overridden  public virtual IEnumerable of ValidationResult Validate(ValidationContext validationContext) 
    /// then this method will be called.  It should of course call :base.Validate
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>true or false</returns>
    private bool SelfValidation(out List<ValidationResult> vResults) {
        var vc = new ValidationContext(this, null, null);
        vResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
        var isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(this, vc, vResults, true);
        return isValid;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does WPF support IValidateObject?

Comment: not sure if WPF directly calls Validate.  MVC and EF do. BUT as this post demonstrates any hook can trigger the call.   I will add a sample of how to hook up... in the meantime this post might prove useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121867/how-can-i-validate-multiple-properties-when-any-of-them-changes